# UIImagePickerController allowsEditing issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` to take an image through the camera and by setting `allowsEditing` to `true` I had hoped to crop the image to a perfect square such as Instagram, ect. I understand there has been a bug since iOS 6 resulting in the cropping box not being able to be dragged. I have been looking for a solution on how to make what I want to happen work, except I can't find anything in Swift. Does anyone know where I should look. By the way the code is this:

```swift
if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
    //load the camera interface
    var picker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.resetBottomBar()
}else{
    //no camera available
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is no camera available", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I Kno.", style: .Default, handler: {(alertAction)in
    alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
}
```

Comment: Easiest thing to do is create your own custom Camera View controller that does what you want. In your case, it will take a square image. Search AVFoundation class